After upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04 I habe many problems
Please help me!
I used to work with Kubuntu 22.04 for a long time without any problems and with regular updating. Then the system asked me to upgrade to 24.04 and I did this at about September 10.
Since then I have a lot of problems (sorry for the long list):
1.
I don't get any updates since then.
2.
Many times my PC is locked for about half a minute or longer, for instance, when thunderbird is getting new messages. Also in Kate when I want to save a new file with a name that already exists. It takes about 20 seconds until the message appears that a file with this name already exists. This locking appears in other instances as well, for instance with Gwenview.
3.
I can't see videos and hear audios. This is a big problem.
4.
I used to dictate text with "Speechnotes" rather the typing it because I have an arm handykap. This doesn't work anymore and this is also a big problem for me.
5.
When I reboot there appears the message "Es kann kein verwendbares Proxy-Einrichtungsskript gefunden werden." (No usable proxy installation script can be found.)
Please help me!
I think the upgrading has damaged my system - and my life since Septemer 10. I have much data on my PC, for instance in my home directory 126 directories and 3900 files.
What can I do?
Should Kubuntu 24.04 be installed from new? But I won't be able to do it myself.

I don't get any updates since then - Apply all the available updates with sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade

I can't see videos and hear audios. This is a big problem. - What exactly happens when you run a video with say, VLC or some other player.
